# Setting all low order bits to 0 until two 1s remain (for a number stored as a byte array)

Tags: c#, .net, binary, bit-manipulation, biginteger

I need to set all the low order bits of a given BigInteger to 0 until only two 1 bits are left. In other words leave the highest and second-highest bits set while unsetting all others.

The number could be any combination of bits. It may even be all 1s or all 0s. Example:

```
MSB    0000 0000
       1101 1010
       0010 0111
       ...
       ...
       ...
LSB    0100 1010
```

We can easily take out corner cases such as 0, 1, PowerOf2, etc. Not sure how to apply popular bit manipulation algorithms on a an array of bytes representing one number.

I have already looked at [bithacks](http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel) but have the following constraints. The BigInteger structure only exposes underlying data through the ToByteArray method which itself is expensive and unnecessary. Since there is no way around this, I don't want to slow things down further by implementing a bit counting algorithm optimized for 32/64 bit integers (which most are).

In short, I have a byte [] representing an arbitrarily large number. Speed is the key factor here.

**NOTE:** In case it helps, the numbers I am dealing with have around 5,000,000 bits. They keep on decreasing with each iteration of the algorithm so I could probably switch techniques as the magnitude of the number decreases.

**Why I need to do this:** I am working with a 2D graph and am particularly interested in coordinates whose x and y values are powers of 2. So (x+y) will always have two bits set and (x-y) will always have consecutive bits set. Given an arbitrary coordinate (x, y), I need to transform an intersection by getting values with all bits unset except the first two MSB.

Comment: sounds somewhat like Project Euler... or what is your case here?

Comment: Will something like [right shift](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.op_rightshift.aspx) be useful?

Comment: Can't you just use BigInteger.log() to find the top two bits? Or is that too inefficient?

Comment: I'm quite confused about those leading zeroes in the example. Is that true? At the moment I believe that BigInteger.ToByteArray will never return something like that.

Comment: @David: Yes, log is a deal breaker. With numbers as large as 2 to the power 5,000,000, the performance hit is too great.

Comment: Log is dramatically more performant than ToByteArray or ToString I believe

Comment: @MareInfinitus: BigInteger sometimes keeps an extra byte to indicate sign. I deliberately included all 0s to make the solution as generic as possible.

Comment: @MareInfinitus: ToByteArray HAS to be calculated in my case anyways so. I use the same byte array to get the MSB to approximate log in certain cases which is lightning fast. BigInteger.Log is not an option.

Comment: I've added more context in case it helps.

Comment: As far as I worked with BigInteger I would still believe that working with Log and creating a new ByteArray is massivly faster than any ToByteArray and scanning. Would be interested in comparisons though.

Comment: @erisco: Actually I've been looking for options like that but I do need to implement a CPU solution to meet a deadline first. Here is my [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12001194/938668) on GPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following (not sure if it's actually valid C#, but it should be close enough):

```
// find the next non-zero byte (I'm assuming little endian) or return -1
int find_next_byte(byte[] data, int i) {
    while (data[i] == 0) --i;
    return i;
}

// find a bit mask of the next non-zero bit or return 0
int find_next_bit(int value, int b) {
    while (b > 0 && ((value & b) == 0)) b >>= 1;
    return b;
}

byte[] data;

int i = find_next_byte(data, data.Length - 1);
// find the first 1 bit
int b = find_next_bit(data[i], 1 << 7);
// try to find the second 1 bit
b = find_next_bit(data[i], b >> 1);
if (b > 0) {
    // found 2 bits, removing the rest
    if (b > 1) data[i] &= ~(b - 1);
} else {
    // we only found 1 bit, find the next non-zero byte
    i = find_next_byte(data, i - 1);
    b = find_next_bit(data[i], 1 << 7);
    if (b > 1) data[i] &= ~(b - 1);
}

// remove the rest (a memcpy would be even better here,
// but that would probably require unmanaged code)
for (--i; i >= 0; --i) data[i] = 0;
```

Untested.

Probably this would be a bit more performant if compiled as unmanaged code or even with a C or C++ compiler.

As harold noted correctly, if you have no a priori knowledge about your number, this `O(n)` method is the best you can do. If you can, you should keep the position of the highest two non-zero bytes, which would drastically reduce the time needed to perform your transformation.

Comment: Thanks. Syntax is not an issue. I can easily port it. Are you assuming little or big endian? My case is little endian so I'll need to adjust it accordingly.

Comment: @Raheel: I just edited to clarify that, I'm scanning from the end of the array, so I'm assuming little endian.

Comment: Thanks. Worst case O(n) should be fine since the loop will terminate early in most cases. I do have another BigInteger for which I already have base 2 Log calculated. How would you approach performing the same operation on that byte array? Just a brief concept should be sufficient.

Comment: As I just noticed, `ToByteArray` always returns the first non-zero byte as the last or second-last element of the array, so finding it is trivial. This also means that knowing the log2 doesn't help you, because that would also only tell you the position of the most significant bit.

Comment: If you already know that your number is binary, you should definitly consider choosing a different representation!

Comment: @Mare: As I take it from the question, the number is more or less random: "The number could be any combination of bits". What other representation would you chose that allows you to do the typical arithmetic operations but supports this particular transformation in a more optimal way?

Comment: @Raheel Knowing baseLog2 you could skip the first b = find_next_bit(data[i], 1 << 7); and replace it with b = 1 << (baseLog2 & 7); and you could also skip the first i = find_next_byte(data, data.Length - 1); and replace it with i = baseLog2 >>3;

Comment: @aka: That wouldn't give any asymptotic improvements though, because the actual work is finding the second bit. The first bit will always be in the first or second byte, so finding it requires only a (small) constant amount of work

Comment: @NiklasB. Agree, a marginal speed up might not be worth the added complexity,  time will be consumed in memset part anyways. Otherwise, if speed was so critical, we could also craft 3 static tables of length 256, one having at most two highest bits set, the other telling number of bits set, and the last only the single bit set, and just index these tables with data[i] appropriately...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is getting optimised out or not but this code appears to be 16x faster than ToByteArray. It also avoids the memory copy and it means you get to the results as uint instead of byte so you should have further improvements there.

```
//create delegate to get private _bit field
var par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(BigInteger));
var bits = Expression.Field(par, "_bits");
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(bits, par);
var func = (Func<BigInteger, uint[]>)lambda.Compile();

//test call our delegate
var bigint = BigInteger.Parse("3498574578238348969856895698745697868975687978");
int time = Environment.TickCount;
for (int y = 0; y < 10000000; y++)
{
    var x = func(bigint);
}
Console.WriteLine(Environment.TickCount - time);

//compare time to ToByteArray
time = Environment.TickCount;
for (int y = 0; y < 10000000; y++)
{
    var x = bigint.ToByteArray();
}
Console.WriteLine(Environment.TickCount - time);
```

From there finding the top 2 bits should be pretty easy. The first bit will be in the first int I presume, then it is just a matter of searching for the second top most bit. If it is in the same integer then just set the first bit to zero and find the topmost bit, otherwise search for the next no zero int and find the topmost bit.

EDIT: to make things simple just copy/paste this class into your project. This creates extension methods that means you can just call mybigint.GetUnderlyingBitsArray(). I added a method to get the Sign also and, to make it more generic, have created a function that will allow accessing any private field of any object. I found this to be slower than my original code in debug mode but the same speed in release mode. I would advise performance testing this yourself.

```
static class BigIntegerEx
{
    private static Func<BigInteger, uint[]> getUnderlyingBitsArray;
    private static Func<BigInteger, int> getUnderlyingSign;

    static BigIntegerEx()
    {
        getUnderlyingBitsArray = CompileFuncToGetPrivateField<BigInteger, uint[]>("_bits");
        getUnderlyingSign = CompileFuncToGetPrivateField<BigInteger, int>("_sign");
    }

    private static Func<TObject, TField> CompileFuncToGetPrivateField<TObject, TField>(string fieldName)
    {
        var par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TObject));
        var field = Expression.Field(par, fieldName);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(field, par);
        return (Func<TObject, TField>)lambda.Compile();
    }

    public static uint[] GetUnderlyingBitsArray(this BigInteger source)
    {
        return getUnderlyingBitsArray(source);
    }

    public static int GetUnderlyingSign(this BigInteger source)
    {
        return getUnderlyingSign(source);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate what's going on here? Are you somehow accessing underlying BigInteger data without calling the ToByteArray method?

Comment: Yes, I am accessing the private field call "_bits". Instead of using reflection (which will be slow) I'm compiling an expression which in my experience is close in speed to regular code.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know you could do that. How can I hook my own code into `func`? I'm not familiar with expressions so will take some time to process this.

Comment: "func" now works like any function except that it is a variable that points to a function (ie a delegate). You just use func(mybigint) and it will return the array. You can run the first 4 lines once, say when the app starts, and store a static reference to func. Rename it to something more friendly of course. One issue I noticed is that for small numbers it stores the entire number in _sign for some reason. You would need to check for that.

Comment: Yes, the problem with this approach is that if BigInteger's internal implementation changes, it will break the application let's say upon upgrading to .NET 4.5. And even for the current implementation, documentation is hard to come by without reflecting and analyzing the source.

Comment: @RaheelKhan Yes, that is a risk you take with this approach but I doubt it will be a problem. BTW, I have updated my answer to make the code simpler to use. There is another option which is to use some third party code. If you have the source then you have access to private variables. I actually wrote something similar to BigInteger in vb6 days.